Short story about a Mercedes Lackey style honorable mercenary company tasked with unethical orders, such as attacking a village
I'm looking for a story I remember, either a standalone short story, or an episode in a longer book, about an honorable mercenary company that is somehow contracted to an unethical leader.  They cannot legally break their contract without facing severe consequences, so they do their best to follow the letter of the orders while minimizing damage to local villagers.  They do things like swinging swords still in sheaths, and hitting the buildings of the village instead of the inhabitants.
I thought this was one of the Tarma and Kethry stories in the "Vows and Honor" books from Mercedes Lackey.  I've been looking through the three, Oathblood, Oathbound, and Oathbreakers, and even extending to Kerowyn's mercenary time in "By the Sword" but I don't see the story.  If it's not these, I have no idea when or where I would have read this.
For people who aren't familiar with Tarma and Kethry, thinking it was them, is because my sense of the village attacked was medieval-ish as was the armor on the fighers, my sense of the unethical leader who had contracted their services was a titled noble, and I am fairly sure there was a strong mercenary guild in the world that would have something to say about breaking a contract.  I also feel like a good portion of the fighters were female, but not all, which would be consistent with Idra's Sunhawks.
I remember one of the fighters thinking something to the effect of "I hope the villagers figure out what we're doing and stay out of the way as much as possible instead of attacking us, so that we don't actually have to kill any of them in self defense."  I also remember someone, perhaps the company comander, being bawled out by the guy hiring them, including something along the lines of "and this time I better see you really attacking the village" as he sent them for probably the third time to raze it.
The mercenary company has in-story discussions among themselves about how to handle the unethical orders, because if they don't follow orders, they are in the wrong because they aren't living up to their contract, but killing innocent villagers is also wrong.

I don't have them close to hand, but maybe one of the Black Company books by Glen Cook? I'm might be mis-remembering something that they had to do.

I just looked up the Black Company books, and they are unfamiliar to me, so that won't be it.  Thank you for the suggestion though.

Kerowyn has a similar story in By the Sword, book 2, chapter 15. If you're right that this is Lackey, then this is probably where.
It doesn't match all of the points, but it hits several: There is a strong Mercenary Guild, the generally honorable Skybolts are caught up in a mess and trapped by their contract, and the employer hard presses the Skybolts to attack harder.
It doesn't specifically have the (un)malicious compliance of attacking while holding back, and the employer is a merchant guild rather than a noble.
After Kerowyn returns to the Skybolts after they were half-destroyed and she got separated fleeing to Karse, the new captain, Ardana, takes a bad contract where they're fighting alongside "the cheapest of free-lancers, one step up from prison scum; drunks and madmen, vicious alley rats who'd knife an ally quick as an enemy." This turns the local population against them, setting traps and ambushes for both sides, including one which takes Kero out of the action.
The merchants who hired them accuse Ardana of slacking off and talk her into a suicidal all-out attack. Kero reads the merchant's minds that they're trying to get out of paying the Skybolts by making sure that there's nobody left to pay.
Kero's uses her injury as a loophole to break her contract and rides off to the Guild to plead her case there.

Sorry, lots of similarities, but this isn't it.  I am specifically looking for the legalistic interpretation of following orders by attacking the village and yet mis-following the orders by striking buildings with swords instead of hurting or killing innocent people.
